# Flag the minimum value in each set of records

Tags: ms-access

I am stuck in marking the minimum value in each set of records. I have a table like one structured below.

```
+-------+--------+----------+
|Prd ID | Price  | isLowest |
+---------------------------+
|00012  | 5      |          |
+---------------------------+
|00012  | 10     |          |
+---------------------------+
|00012  | 15     |          |
+---------------------------+
|00012  | 20     |          |
+---------------------------+
|00222  | 50     |          |
+---------------------------+
|00222  | 60     |          |
+---------------------------+
|00222  | 70     |          |
+---------------------------+
```

I want to have "Yes" in the isLowest column for each set of records. I mean by set of records as Prd ID is same i.e 00012 and 00222. I want the following output

```
+-------+--------+----------+
|Prd ID | Price  | isLowest |
+---------------------------+
|00012  | 5      |  Yes     |
+---------------------------+
|00012  | 10     |          |
+---------------------------+
|00012  | 15     |          |
+---------------------------+
|00012  | 20     |          |
+---------------------------+
|00222  | 50     |  Yes     |
+---------------------------+
|00222  | 60     |          |
+---------------------------+
|00222  | 70     |          |
+---------------------------+
```

**I can get the minimum values for each set of Prd IDs however, I can't flag this in the iswinner column**

To get the minimum values I use the following query.

```
SELECT tbl.prdid, Min(tbl.price) AS Price
FROM tbl
GROUP BY tbl.prdid
```

Comment: MS-Access as the question title says.

Comment: You'd better show what you've tried so far.

Comment: You simply need to Join your original table with a subquery that returns the minimal value of each prd ID. The use a calculated field to create the isLowest column

Comment: Can you create a valid Access `GROUP BY` query which returns the minimum *Price* for each *Prd ID*?  If yes, add the SQL from that query to your question and we can show you how to get from there to your final goal.

Comment: Yes I included the query to get the minimum price records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reconsider whether you actually need *isLowest* as a field in the table.  You can easily determine its value with a query whenever you need to see it.

```sql
SELECT
    t.prdid,
    t.price,
    IIf(t.Price = sub.MinPrice, 'Yes', '') AS [isLowest]
FROM
    tbl AS t
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT tbl.prdid, Min(tbl.price) AS MinPrice
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY tbl.prdid
    ) AS sub
    ON t.prdid = sub.prdid;
```